Word for the dust carried by wind
Is there a word for the dust that is carried by the wind and gradually accumulates?
In US English 'silt' almost fits:

earthy matter, fine sand, or the like carried by moving or running water and deposited as a sediment. (dictionary.com)

but in British English it is not quite right:

a fine deposit of mud, clay, etc, esp one in a river or lake
(dictionary.com)

The stuff I see is like fine sand and weeds grow in it. The weeds trap more dust from the wind, die and rot down, providing compost so the next generation of weeds can be bigger. After a few years, there is a decent layer of soil.

Silt normally refers to stuff deposited by rivers or other water, not wind-blown matter. Where are you seeing this dust? Is it general household dust, urban or rural, or particularly soil, sand, etc, in natural settings? And looking for a technical or everyday term? I'd expect it to be referred to generally as built-up/accumulated dust/dirt in an urban situation, although geologists have their own terms.

Loess is the geological term.
According to Wikipedia:

A loess (US: /ˈlɛs, ˈlʌs, ˈloʊ.əs/, UK: /ˈloʊ.əs, ˈlɜːs/; from German: Löss [lœs]) is a clastic, predominantly silt-sized sediment that is formed by the accumulation of wind-blown dust. Ten percent of Earth's land area is covered by loesses or similar deposits.

(Clastic refers to rock formed from broken pieces of rocks.)
It's also in Merriam-Webster; Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus labels it as uncountable, and the examples in Merriam-Webster seem to agree. Although few nouns are always uncountable, typical examples are like this (M-W quoting Forbes, 2021):

Soils here are particularly complex, featuring chalk, sand, gravel, clay, loess, quartzite and slate.


Good suggestion! The sticking point is that definitions suggest light brown, grey or yellowish-grey. What I have seen is black - I have seen it in roof guttering (where not washed away by rain), along roads and paths (often at the base of walls or bottom of slopes) and even in the open country, tending to fill in dips. Stuart's comment about accumulated dust/dirt is what I would prefer.
